# Name & notation for the collection of a matrix's singular values

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, terminology, svd, singular-values

I've often seen the notion of the ***spectrum*** of a matrix $A \in \mathbb{F}^{n \times n}$ ([Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_of_a_matrix)),

$$\sigma(A) := \{ \lambda \in \mathbb{F} \mid \lambda \text{ is an eigenvalue of $A$} \}$$

(to be interpreted as a multiset).

Is there such a name or notation for the collection of ***singular values*** of a matrix?

I've been wondering since it would compactify some of my writing as I study some linear algebra on my own (it gets tedious to keep seeing and writing "... is a singular value of" over and over again, in my opinion). Of course, since this is moreso self-study, I could just come up with my own convention, but I was wondering if there was a standard name/notation for the multiset of singular values? It certainly feels like one should exist considering their importance, but I've had no luck in finding one.

Comment: The notation $\vec s(A)$ is used in Bhatia's *Matrix Analysis* to refer to the vector of singular values of $A$, I believe. I don't know of any relevant notation that's used more widely than that, though. I recommend coming up with your own notation.